# Hiding SDK add-ons

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How to make an SDK add-on hidden in Mozilla Firefox. I mean, there are add-ons which are installed in Firefox browser but not visible in about:addons. When I am using AddonManager service and printing all installed add-ons, there is a list of add-ons which I could not find them in about:add-ons. I think they are default add-ons given my Mozilla and genuine add-ons. So I am looking for those type of add-ons

I need this information to include countermeasures for hidden add-ons in my add-on.

Comment: I think its about:addons not about:extensions and Can you please give names of the addon which does this?

Comment: @Andy, There are a few "add-ons" which are distributed with Firefox which are not displayed. These are loaded from *[install directory]/browser/features* In FF50.0.2 these include: `aushelper@mozilla.org`, `e10srollout@mozilla.org`, `firefox@getpocket.com`, and `webcompat@mozilla.org`. There is also the Default Theme, `{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}`, displayed under Appearance, found in *[install directory]/browser/extensions*, which might be misconstrued as not being displayed due to being an "add-on", but shown under Appearance.

Comment: @Andy, The quickest place to see a reference to these add-ons is in the value for `extensions.xpiState` which can be viewed from `about:config`.

Comment: @Andy, Once a non-WebExtensions add-on is installed, it could be written to hide itself from being listed in `about:add-ons`. However, I doubt that one which did so would be able to pass review and be listed on AMO (with the possible exception that it might be permitted if the user was *explicitly* informed that this was going to be done, but even then I would consider it a maybe, at best). One of the powerful things about Firefox is that Add-ons can have a great amount of control over the UI. That will, unfortunately, all go away once WebExtensions are the only permitted type of extension.

Comment: While there may be a specific way which these add-ons are hidden (I have not looked at their code, or in the Firefox source code), an add-on could easily be programmed in a large number of different ways to hide itself from view in `about:addons`. Thus, there is no convenient way which is guaranteed to single out such add-ons from other add-ons which are installed (other than that they are installed, but not visibly displayed).

Comment: This looks like a question which might be an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). Please describe in more detail what it is you are attempting to achieve and why you are concerned about having "countermeasures for hidden add-ons in my add-on".

Comment: @Makyen I had developed a security extension. I want to test it against hidden add-ons and detecting an add-on which is hidden. So, I want to write a hidden add-on myself and use it for testing.